# Using sendmmsg with a link layer socket in Go

Tags: linux, go, sockets

I'm trying to use Go to call the `sendmmsg` syscall to send a datagram multiple times over a link layer socket. I've used Gopacket to build the datagram, and when I send it using `unix.Sendto()` it works as expected. When I use `sendmmsg` the program panics and returns an error `message too long`. Here's what I've tried so far (error handling removed for brevity):

```
// Open an AF_PACKET type socket
fd, _ := unix.Socket(unix.AF_PACKET, unix.SOCK_RAW, unix.ETH_P_ALL)

// Create a link layer Sockaddr
sockaddr := &unix.SockaddrLinklayer{
  Protocol: unix.ETH_P_ALL,
  Ifindex: 5,
  Hatype: 803,
  Pkttype: 0,
  Halen: 0,
}
```

`sendmmsg` takes a file descriptor (fd), a pointer to an array of `mmsghdr` structures, an unsigned int `vlen` which is the length of the array of `mmsghdr` structs, and a `flags` value. So using Go, assuming I'm not passing any flags and that I have an array of `mmsghdr` structs of length 2 called `mymsgvec`, I should be able to send my datagram with:

```
unix.Syscall6(unix.SYS_SENDMMSG, 
  uintptr(fd), 
  (uintptr)(unsafe.Pointer(mymsgvec)),
  uintptr(2),
  0, 0, 0)
```

To create `mymsgvec` I first define a `mmsghdr` type following its description in the `sendmmsg` [manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendmmsg.2.html):

```
type mmsghdr struct {
  msghdr unix.Msghdr
  msglen uint32
}
```

I then create a `msghdr` from my buffer `buf`:

```
msghdr := &unix.Msghdr {
  Name: (*byte)(unsafe.Pointer(sockaddr)),
  Namelen: uint32(unsafe.Sizeof(*sockaddr)),
  Iov: &unix.Iovec {
    Base: &buf[0],
    Len: uint64(len(buf)),
  },
  Iovlen: uint64(1),
}
```

Then finally I create `mymsgvec` with

```
mymsgvec := &[]mmsghdr{
  {msghdr: *msghdr, msglen: uint32(len(msg))},
  {msghdr: *msghdr, msglen: uint32(len(msg))},
}
```

When I try to send this using `unix.Syscall6` as described above it fails with the error `message too long`, although the message is only 44 bytes. I assume the issue is something to do with how I'm constructing `mmsghdr`s, but I'm not sure. Could someone please point to where I'm going wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you reference

https://github.com/golang/net/blob/v0.20.0/internal/socket/mmsghdr_unix.go#L148

maybe not set `mmsghdr.msglen` ?